# How to call a method from base class where the base class is a template parameter

Tags: c++

i have a c++ class like the below one working at vc++ , but doesnt work anymore in linux gcc 4.7. And i have no idea how to make it work again.

test.h

```
template<typename a>
class test: public a
{
public:
    void fun();
};
```

test.cpp

```
template<typename a>
void test<a>::fun()
{
   template_class_method(); <-- this is a public method from template_class 
}
    template class test<template_class>;
```

template_class.h

```
class template_class {
public:
    template_class();
    virtual ~template_class();
    void template_class_method();

};
```

template_class.cpp

```
#include "templateclass.h"

template_class::template_class() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

template_class::~template_class() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

void template_class::template_class_method() {
}
```

Comment: doesn't work anymore, means you get compiler errors ? Show them

Comment: my bad. Error - there are no arguments to ‘template_class_method’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘template_class_method’ must be available [-fpermissive].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to qualify it with the base class name as:

```
a::template_class_method();
```

The qualification `a::` is necessary because `template_class_method` exists in `a`. The C++ rule is that if the base is a class template or template argument, then all its members are **not** automatically visible to the derived classes. In order to help the compiler to find the member, you need to tell it to *look for the member* in the base class, for which you need to qualify the member which is of the form of `base::member_function()` or `base::member_data`.

In your case, since the base is `a`, and the member is `template_class_method`, so you have to write this:

```
a::template_class_method();
```

Note that such a base class is called *dependent* base class since it *depends* on the template argument.

Comment: @BryanFok: `base` of course is not a name. You need to write `a`.

Comment: i got an error. there are no arguments to ‘template_class_method’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘template_class_method’ must be available [-fpermissive]

Comment: @BryanFok: That is *another* problem. Now you need to show more code, the relevant code, such as what you're passing as template argument to `test` and how you have defined that type?

Comment: @BryanFok: You need to write `template class test<template_class>;` **after** the class definition of `template_class`, **not before** it.

Comment: I am so sorry. That was just my editing mistake on the post. I believe the error has nothing to do with that.

Comment: @BryanFok: Your code is messed up, I can't be sure which code is where exactly. Just a question: you've written `template class test<template_class>;` just after `fun()` implementation, so is the class `template_class` visible at that site?

Comment: I have tidy up the code, it was a quick example, sorry for the mess up. template class test<template_class>; is written at the end of  test.cpp file

Comment: error gone! thanks Nawaz. missed a:: indeed. Learned something new today. Thanks. Trying to convert the whole program from Window to Linux.

Comment: @BryanFok: How can you forget `a::` when I have repeated it twice in my post? Anyway, you fixed it now.

Comment: no no. I meant I have not put a:: at the first place, before i made this post.

Comment: @BryanFok: One important point: the definition of all members of class template should present in the header file itself. In your case, `test` is a class template, so all its members [such as `fun` member function] should be defined in the header file. So move the definition from `test.cpp` to the `test.h`. It should work.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why @Karthik T deleted the answer, but that answer was on the right path. You have several options

1. Use qualified name `a::template_class_method()`

   ```
   template<typename a>
   class test : public a
   {
   public:
     void fun()
     {
       a::template_class_method();
     }
   };
   ```
2. Use class member access syntax `this->template_class_method()`

   ```
   template<typename a>
   class test : public a
   {
   public:
     void fun()
     {
       this->template_class_method();
     }
   };
   ```
3. Make the base class method visible through using-declaration

   ```
   template<typename a>
   class test : public a
   {
   public:
     using a::template_class_method;
     void fun()
     {
       template_class_method();
     }
   };
   ```

Note that the first method will suppress the virtuality of `template_class_method` (in cases when it is virtual), so it should be used with caution. For this reason, method number 2 is preferred, since it preserves the natural behavior of `template_class_method`.

Your comment stating that `this->template_class_method()` "doesn't work" is unclear. It works without any problems. Moreover, as I said above, this is in general case a better option than using a qualified name.